# KL divergence between Exponential and Normal distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, exponential-distribution

What is the KL divergence $KL(P \;\Vert\; Q)$ between an Exponential distribution $P = \text{Exp}(\lambda)$ and a Normal distribution $Q = \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$?

I have not found any source for this problem and because the integration by hand is difficult, I would like to have some confirmation.

The integral is given by

$$KL(P \;\Vert\; Q) = \int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \log\Biggl( \frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}} \Biggr) dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a little bit of short hand let
$$
\langle h(X) \rangle = \mathbb{E}[h(X)] = \int h(X)p(x)dx,
$$
so
$$
\begin{align}
D_{KL}(P \| Q) &= \langle \log p(X) \rangle -\langle \log q(X) \rangle,
\end{align}
$$
Then considering seperately you need to do the integrals
$$
\langle \log p(X) \rangle = \langle \log \lambda -\lambda X\rangle =\log \lambda - \lambda \langle X\rangle,
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\langle \log Q(X) \rangle &= \left\langle \log \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right)\right\rangle  \\
&= -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\langle(X-\mu)^2\rangle -\frac{1}{2}\log (2\pi\sigma^2),
\end{align}
$$
which assuming I haven't blundered along the way should be easy enough for you to continue onwards. One check/interesting result is that minimising $D_{KL}(P\| Q)$ with respect to the parameter $(\mu, \sigma^2)$ *should* be equivalent to moment matching.

Comment: Using expectations makes this a lot easier! Is the equivalence a general property of the KL divergence?

Comment: The equivalence in the comment about moment matching? Its a general result for exponential family distributions a proof of which is sketched at the end of [these notes](https://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/mlpr/2017/notes/w9a_variational_kl.pdf)